# Timestamp string to seconds in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a large dataframe containing a Timestamp column like the one shown below:

```
Timestamp
16T122109960
16T122109965
16T122109970
16T122109975
[73853 rows x 1 columns]
```

I need to convert this into a seconds (formatted 12.523) since first timestamp column using something like this:

```
start_time = log_file['Timestamp'][0]
log_file['Timestamp'] = log_file.Timestamp.apply(lambda x: x - start_time)
```

But first I need to parse the timestamps into seconds as quickly as possible, I've tried using regex to split the timestamp into hours, minuntes, seconds, and milliseconds and then multipling & dividing appropriatly but was given a memory error. Is there a function within datetime or dateutils that would help?

The method I have used at the moment is below:

```
def regex_time(time):
    list = re.split(r"(\d*)(T)(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{3})", time)
    date, delim, hours, minutes, seconds, mills = list[1:-1]
    seconds = int(seconds)
    seconds += int(mills) /1000
    seconds += int(minutes) * 60
    seconds += int(hours) * 3600
    return seconds

df['Timestamp'] = df.Timestamp.apply(lambda j: regex_time(j))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to convert the timestamp to datetime format and then extract the seconds in the format you want.

Here I attach you a code sample of how it works:

```
from datetime import datetime

timestamp = 1545730073
dt_object = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)

seconds = dt_object.strftime("%S.%f")
print(seconds)
```

Output:

```
53.000000
```

You can also apply it to the dataframe you are using, for instance:

```
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':[1545730073]})

df['datetime'] = df['timestamp'].apply(lambda x: datetime.fromtimestamp(x))
df['seconds'] = df['datetime'] .apply(lambda x : x.strftime("%S.%f"))
```

And it will return a dataFrame containing:

```
    timestamp   datetime                 seconds
0   1545730073  2018-12-25 10:27:53     53.000000
```

Comment: you're converting a posix timestamp; however the OP's timestamps (e.g. `16T122109960`) aren't exactly posix...

Answer (score 0):

you could parse the string with `strptime`, subtract the `start_time` as a `pd.Timestamp` and use the `total_seconds()` of the resulting `timedelta`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp': ['16T122109960','16T122109965','16T122109970','16T122109975']})

start_time = pd.Timestamp('1900-01-01')
df['totalseconds'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], format='%dT%H%M%S%f')-start_time).dt.total_seconds()

df['totalseconds']
# 0    1340469.960
# 1    1340469.965
# 2    1340469.970
# 3    1340469.975
# Name: totalseconds, dtype: float64
```

To use the first entry of the 'Timestamp' column as reference time `start_time`, use

```
start_time = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'].iloc[0], format='%dT%H%M%S%f')
```